# How to read one full line, followed by reading only the last five characters?

Tags: python, file

I am new to Python. I want to read a JSON file from monitoring. The file looks like this

I only want the timestamp, the system name like "test-1" and the numbers from power, disk and CPU.

My script looks like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.3

import os
import json 

    with open('test.json', 'r') as f:
        distros_dict = json.load(f)

    for distro in distros_dict:
        print(distro['"power [W]"'])
```

Update:
How do i write them to variables?

New Sample Data:

```
[
   {
      "Area":"CLOUD",
      "timestamp":"2019-11-06T00:00:00",
      "Systeme":{
         "test-4":{
            "power [W]":181.05,
            "disk [%]":52.28
         },
         "test-1":{
            "power [W]":280.56,
            "disk[%]":6.33,
            "cpu[%]":0.1
         },
         "test-2":{
            "power [W]":271.84,
            "disk[%]":6.52,
            "cpu[%]":0.1
         },      
         "test-8":{
            "power [W]":453.56,
            "disk[%]":93.63,
            "cpu[%]":5.04
         }
      }
   }
]
```

The Output variables i want are cpu,power and disk
Instead of printing them to commandline i want write them in the three variables

Comment: Who is jason???

Comment: Where is the ```"Stomverbrauch [W]"``` coming from? You should change your ```for distro in distros_dict``` to ```for distro in distros_dict["Systeme"]``` then you can access the power by using ```distro["power [W]"]```

Comment: Please describe the output you desire. Read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Stromverbrauch is the german word for the power

Comment: explain why you have `, ...` at the end of your json because that not the right json format. if you want multiple dict it json it supposed to be the following format `[{ }, { }]`

Comment: the 3 points are there because i didnt want to show all 5 hundred lines of the document

Comment: @leoStahl Linh's point is that the file should begin with a `[` and you aren't showing it in your sample input. Does it or does it not have a `[` in the beginning?

Comment: Yes it has my files are a valid JSON files

Comment: You mean 3 variables that are list ?because you have multiple test objects with power disk and cpu ,pls write out the desired output as it really hard to understand what you want

Comment: Note that you don't write anything to a variable in python. Variables are just names that are associated with some objects and don't possess any memory themselves(except for some bookkeeping things). For example, `a = b = 4; id(a) == id(b)'. Therefore, there is no such thing as variable declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list of tuples to store your variables. Here is an example of how you can do this.

```
import json
import sys

data = None

with open('test.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

# since we are dealing with input from another source, we should validate it every step of the way
# check if there was no data in the file
if not data:
    sys.exit(0)



variables = []  # this list would contain tuples. The tuple would contain system name, cpu, power, and disk. Any missing data would be set as None
for distro in data:
    if 'Systeme' not in distro:  # we verify this attribute exists
        continue
    for system_name, system in distro['Systeme'].items():
         variables.append( 
             (system_name, system.get('cpu[%]'), system.get('power [W]'), system.get('disk[%]'))
         )

# now that we have them stored inside the 'variables' list, we can print them to verify that they are stored.
for system_name, cpu, power, disk in variables:
    print(system_name, cpu, power, disk)
    # do other stuff with these variables here if you want.
```

Answer (score 2):

your json file with multi dict supposed to follow this format:

```
[    
    { 
        "Area": "CLOUD",
        "timestamp": "2019-11-06T12:24:25",
        "Systeme": {
            "test-1": {
                "power [W]": 181.05,
                "disk [%]": 52.28
            },
            "test-2": {
                "power [W]": 199.67,
                "disk [%]": 54.47
            },
            "test-3": {
                "power [W]": 175.68,
                "disk [%]": 10.17,
                "cpu [%]": 22.43
            }
        }
    },
    { 
        "Area": "CLOUD",
        "timestamp": "2019-11-06T12:24:25",
        "Systeme": {
            "test-1": {
                "power [W]": 181.05,
                "disk [%]": 52.28
            },
            "test-2": {
                "power [W]": 199.67,
                "disk [%]": 54.47
            },
            "test-3": {
                "power [W]": 175.68,
                "disk [%]": 10.17,
                "cpu [%]": 22.43
            }
        }
    }
]
```

You just need to combine the values from each dictionary into a string for the result:

```
with open('test.json', 'r') as f:
    distros_dict = json.load(f)

test_keys = ['power [W]', 'disk [%]', 'cpu [%]']

for distro in distros_dict:
    for key, value in distro['Systeme'].items():
        output_list =[]
        output_list.append(key)
        for single_system_key, single_system_value in distro['Systeme'][key].items():
           if single_system_key in test_keys:
              output_list.append(single_system_value)
        print(' - '.join(str(e) for e in output_list))
```

Final output get you:

```
test-1 - 181.05 - 52.28
test-2 - 199.67 - 54.47
test-3 - 175.68 - 10.17 - 22.43
test-1 - 181.05 - 52.28
test-2 - 199.67 - 54.47
test-3 - 175.68 - 10.17 - 22.43
```

Comment: i Tried what you told but now i get this error `test.py", line 10, in <module>
    for key, value in distro['Systeme'].items():
TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: because your json format is wrong, look at the format of the json in my answer

Comment: This will fail if one of the keys doesn't exist, e.g. cpu as seen in test-3

Comment: well you just need to check if key exists which is pretty simple, @leo Stahl i had edit my answer to check if key exist

Comment: how do write that now to different variables

Comment: What do you mean by different variables ? If you have more key in each test you can add them to the test_key list

Comment: I dont want to add a key i want to write the output to variables named like they keys

Comment: then you need to fix your question with the part `The output should be:` as it contradict what you really want in your question. If you just want it to display like dicts in `test` why not just the entire dict inside the `test` ? instead of getting separate values

Answer (score 2):

Set your dictionary (json format, check if it's using the correct format on https://jsonlint.com/ )

```
dict = {
  "Area": "CLOUD",
    "timestamp": "2019-11-06T12:24:25",
    "Systeme": {
        "test-1": {
            "power [W]": 181.05,
            "disk [%]": 52.28
        },
        "test-2": {
            "power [W]": 199.67,
            "disk [%]": 54.47
        },
        "test-3": {
            "power [W]": 175.68,
            "disk [%]": 10.17,
             "cpu [%]": 22.43
}}}
```

Load your dictionary as json

```
import json
x = json.loads(json.dumps(dict))
```

Loop through your dict[Systeme] and grab all of the properties you need to print. 
I've chosen to use `dict.get("systeme")` rather than `dict["Systeme"]` because you're missing the cpu in test-3

```
for line in x["Systeme"]:
    power = x.get("Systeme").get(line).get("power [W]", "")
    disk = x.get("Systeme").get(line).get("disk [%]", "")
    cpu = x.get("Systeme").get(line).get("cpu [%]", "")
    print(f"{line} {power} {disk} {cpu}")
    power, disk, cpu = "", "", ""
```

Note: the example above is Python 3.7+, the print statement needs to be changed for earlier versions of Python:
`print("%s %s %s %s"%(line, power, disk, cpu) )`

Comment: Which python version are you using? This is Python 3.7+

Comment: Added an alternative print function for earlier versions of Python

Comment: My bad, it was python 3.6+

Comment: It does not work on python 3.7 i get the Error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/test/Dokument/Feab/test2.py", line 23, in <module>
    for line in x["Systeme"]:
TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Answer (score 0):

you can try out this approach. you will need to install pandas for it

**pip install pandas**

```
import json
import pandas as pd
data = json.load(open('data.json'))  // asuming your data is in data.json


new_json=[]
for rec in data:
    new_doc = {}
    for key in rec:
        if type(rec[key]) is str:
            new_doc[key] = rec[key]
        else:
            for key1 in rec[key]:
                if type(rec[key][key1]) is str:
                    new_doc[key+'_'+key1] = rec[key][key1]
                else:
                    for key2 in rec[key][key1]:
                        if type(rec[key][key1][key2]) in [str,float,int]:
                            new_doc[key+'_'+key1+'_'+key2] = rec[key][key1][key2]
                        else:
                            print("don't support more nested json")
    new_json.append(new_doc)

data = pd.DataFrame(new_json)
data.head()  //peak into your new data structure][1]][1]
```

now you will have a well formatted table structure and can do any query on it.
so to get all type-1-power and timestamp simply do

```
data[['Systeme_test-1_power [W]','timestamp']]
```

We can do a lot other type of query and graph plotting from here very easily.
Read panda docs for more or comment if you have doubt